# OP asked an additional/follow on question in the comments to the answer - New question or edit OP

Tags: discussion, questions

I answered the question below and it solved the error they were getting.

[Search string in SQL LIKE in multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837187/search-string-in-sql-like-in-multiple-rows)

However, they have then asked an additional/follow-on question in the comments.

I haven't replied yet as I'm not sure what the best action is.

Do I ask them to create a new question?

Or

Do I get them to add it to the original question?

Either way, I know nothing is useful by being in the comments as they can be removed anytime.

Comment: _"Do i ask them to create a new question?"_ I would do this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yeh, i was moving towards that. Someone has also commented that on the question and i think they have followed the advice

Comment: Useful reading: [Exit strategies for "Chameleon Questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/616624).

Answer (score 4):

OP should ask a new question. Edits to a question after answers have been received are only a good idea to either clarify minor details or for formatting.

In this specific case, asking a new question with the new code that doesn't have the original error anymore sounds perfectly reasonable. You can tell OP in the comments to do so.

Answer (score -6):

Perhaps this wasn't a close reason at the time, but I had this exact situation come up and voted to close the top-level question itself as needing focus.  Others may disagree but I don't think it's at all appropriate to move the goalposts.

Comment: Asking a follow up question when the original question on it's own was fine is imho not "moving the goalpost". It probably shouldn't be an edit to the question, but as a new question I don't see any problems with that.

Comment: If an OP edits the new question into the original question, the appropriate thing to do is to rollback the edit and inform the OP of the policy, not close the question.