# How to handle an OP's new issues that appear after answering?

Tags: discussion, questions

A user asked the question [Yii2 validation rule for multiple inputs with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738180/yii2-validation-rule-for-multiple-inputs-with-same-name/30742373?noredirect=1#comment49576378_30742373) which I answered. They then commented:

> Thanks. Your code works fine if these kind of multiple inputs already exist in a form but when I add new inputs using jQuery in a form then it does not work. So please can you assist me for that ?

After a bit of probing, I recommended that they ask a new question instead of editing the current one to include this information, because

1. in my opinion these are two separate issues
2. the new issue was (probably) javascript and not php
3. I couldn't answer the new issue without some research and more detail. By asking a new question, they could get a better answer faster.

Was this the correct way to handle this?

Comment: [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: _"Was this the correct way to handle this?"_ Yes.

Comment: Related: [OP asked an additional follow-on question in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282979), [Follow-on question vs edit to original: when to use which](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746)

Comment: @JoshCaswell the last question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746 is a better fit.

Comment: I picked the other one because [q/290746](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290746) is from the point of view of the asker, but whatever you say.