# How much follow up is normal for a question?

Tags: discussion

In response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111369/how-to-follow-seaborns-examples).  The original question was "where is this dataset?" and the follow up question is "Find compatible versions of Seaborn and Matplotlib."  As a newer user, what is a rollback? When is it appropriate to use them?  Do I have enough reputation to use this function and is there a 'rollback' badge?

**Update:**

thanks gnat, I am convinced this is a duplicate of "How to handle OP's new issues that appear after answering?" and not "Follow on" question vs edit to original.  I am going to redirect people to the second one when this issue arises in the future.  Reading "exit strategies for chameleon questions" was really helpful.  I learned that this is called a "chameleon question".  The joys of being new.

Comment: see also [How to handle an OP's new issues that appear after answering?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296600/how-to-handle-an-ops-new-issues-that-appear-after-answering)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and the follow up question is

Follow up questions should be, you know, new questions. If it's something really minor a comment may be appropriate.

I honestly don't have enough experience with the language/library in this specific case, but seeing as how the "update" is longer than the original question, it probably should be a new question.

[It looks like you don't have the rep to roll back edits yet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271934/how-do-you-rollback). Rolling back requires 2k rep and comes with [the full edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), so for the time being you can flag it for moderator attention. Be sure to be specific in any custom mod flag, tell them exactly what you think the problem is and what you expect to be done about it.