# What do I do with a question that changed thanks to a posted answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38545544/merge-dataframes-on-two-columns) and, thanks to the answer and the following comments, I realized that it could not be solved in the way I posed in the first place. Thanks to that I could solve it in a different way.

The answer didn't solve the initial question (could not have done in any case), but led to insights that solved the problem (by changing it). That makes me want to accept it as actual answer.

I edited the question to clarify and posted the late answer.

Is that ok?
Should I post it as answer myself and accept the one that helped?

Comment: related: [How much follow up is normal for a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311845/how-much-follow-up-is-normal-for-a-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer didn't solve the initial question

Technically the question was a 2 part question:

> What am I missing?
>
> And why do I get `c.shape = (12,6)` in the first example?

The answer'er answered the second question and in doing so ultimately answered the first question.

If you posted the edit to your question as an answer, then it wouldn't actually be answering your original question. You could rephrase the wording of your edit so that it no longer poses a new question, and add that as an answer.

I'm not a wordsmith, nor do I know much about the topic, but something like the following could suffice:

> Thanks to [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547935/776515) I realized that the underlying problem is that there is not a single combination of columns to do that. Thus the merge problem, as posed before cannot be univocally solved.
>
> Therefore, I ended up making a univocal relationship between the tables by using a dictionary that maps the desired outputs that need to be aligned.
>
> ```
> map_ab = { 'num1':'let1', 'num2':'let2' }
> b['let'] = b.apply( lambda x: map_ab[x['num']], axis=1 )
> c = pd.merge( a, b, on=['foo', 'bar', 'let'] )
> print( c )
> ```

I would definitely mark [piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547935/776515) as accepted though, since he *did* answer your question.

Comment: He *did* answer the question, indeed. I guess that's the main point here. That, and [*Editing your question potentially invalidates any existing answers*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290747/776515).