# Should I downvote questions that are legitimate but that are asked by a clueless user?

Tags: discussion

I have been coming across this scenario more and more: a user will ask a legitimate question about a slighter newer content area (mostly language processing/deep learning stuff) and I will either try to answer it, or more often watch others answer it. Then it turns out that the OP has so little understanding of the programming language they're working in that they cannot use the answer. Then either I, or the other answerer, gets mired down responding to trivial questions in comments about how to install packages or what certain lines of code in the answer means.

I am a bit confused about what the best response would be to this situation. It feels a little bit like casting pearls before swine. I cannot decide if I should downvote questions once it becomes apparent that the OP doesn't know what they're talking about - this doesn't seem justified if the question is perfectly fine on its own (ignoring subsequent comments) and could probably help *others* in the future.

At this point, I'll probably just avoid interacting with these questions in the future, unless someone has a better suggestion/standard operating procedure. It can be challenging to figure out when to bail, if it turns out your OP is an endless pit of RTFM questions. Especially given that 99% of the reason anyone answers a question is because they want to *help*, it's disheartening to find out your answer is complete gibberish to someone who doesn't know how a function works.

Comment: What do you mean by "legitimate"?  Lots of people tend to use it to mean that it's a question about a problem that the author actually has, which doesn't mean it's actually a good question (for the site).

Comment: Related: ["You're Unclear on What You're Asking"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291866/youre-unclear-on-what-youre-asking); also maybe useful: [Can we please have the "Lacks Minimal Understanding" close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back)

Comment: Downvotes always are about the quality of the content and helpfulness for future research, no matter how _clueless_ the specific user (OP) is actually.

Comment: You should downvote posts that deserve downvotes. the user's abilities aren't relevant.

Comment: And from MSE [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296600/how-to-handle-an-ops-new-issues-that-appear-after-answering)

Comment: @ryanyuyu I saw those duplicates, but I wasn't certain if a user not being able to import packages constituted a "new issue" considering it was a barrier to them being able to use the answer given to the original question.

Comment: @Servy I meant legitimate in terms of a good question by the standards of SO, however, writing my question did clarify my thoughts and I realized that part of this is probably me (and others) needing to do a better job of discerning which questions are asking for overly specific implementation of something. This is usually a red flag that the question is actually a RFTM related to the content/framework. Trivial questions related to something like Tensorflow can be harder to identify than trivial questions related to Python.

Comment: This was one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53638903/python-machine-learning-classifying-words-in-sentence#53639411. With Servy's prompting I'm realizing this was a bad question to begin with and should have been flagged. Thanks.

Comment: What I often end up doing in similar cases is commenting that I've answered the question that was asked and that any follow-up should be in a new question. Can't use it every where, but it avoids long comments "tails" and leaves the Q&A in a useable state.

Comment: You should never vote on users specifically, only the content. Judge the content soley on the content, not the user.

Comment: If it's a good question, answer it.  If the OP starts drilling you for further questions, which you deem as them showing a lack of basic understanding, don't down vote, just walk away.  I would argue this is one version of a help vampire.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As someone with experience intentionally answering (surprisingly) well-written or interesting questions by known help vampires for the benefit of future readers, my best advice to you is... honestly, don't respond to their follow-up questions unless you feel like it (and even if you're in a really good mood, try to take it to chat as soon as you can and hope they follow).

If it compels you to be polite about declining their follow-up questions, say something like "I'm sorry but that's outside the scope of your question" and leave it at that. After they've stopped and some time has passed you may flag the comments as no longer needed.

As for voting on the question, as others have said, vote on the content, not the user. If the user asked a question that's ultimately going to be very useful to future readers in the long run, well, like it or not (and whether they themself realize this or not) they earned it. Yes, in an ideal world, somebody who understands the technology they're working with, asks competent questions and can understand the answers given to them would be asking these questions, but sometimes these questions end up getting asked by people who don't know better, resulting in frustration for everyone involved. And the community frowns on asking duplicate questions to get away from help vampires, so there doesn't appear to be any other solution besides dealing with the question as posted by whomever has posted it.

Of course, if the question itself is so poorly researched or poorly written as to not seem worth the trouble I suggest (to you and to anyone else answering their questions) holding off on answering it until it has been edited into shape, either by them or the community. As far as the site is concerned our priority is high quality Q&A, and any user, new or experienced (with the site, not the subject matter), is equally capable of asking a useful, high quality question or a less-than-useful, low quality one. And votes should reflect this accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

It's somewhat irrelevant whether the *user* is clueless, experienced, polite or rude - you're voting the content, not the user.  As for voting the content, even then it's debatable. Not everybody here can agree about the purpose of downvotes, neither the actions that would be best for the long term goals of the site. So it depends what your view of voting is, and what you want to use this feature for on the site.

If you think it's to **reduce visibility of uninteresting content**, and upvoting is to help good content bubble to the top, then **by all means downvote** the boring RTFM questions - even if they are well-written and "legitimate" whatever that means.

If you view voting as **a stick/carrot to try and discourage/encourage the asking of questions in a way that's beneficial for the site**, then maybe a downvote is not good. Finding an appropriate duplicate to link is probably more helpful, or just moving along. And if you actually feel the question *"could probably help others in the future"*, or could attract such an answer, then that seems more upvoteable in this context. Be aware that often really basic questions already have some high quality answers on site, and adding new answers on dupe questions is not really improving signal to noise ratio for stack overflow.